# JavaScript: creating an inheritance function based on a prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I want to create an inheritance function based on a prototype.  I have this JavaScript:

```
Function.prototype.Inherits = function(parent) {
    this.prototype = new parent();
    this.prototype.constructor = this;
};

function Base() {};

function Foo() {
    this.Inherits(Base);
};
```

I want a function that does the same as this:

```
Foo.prototype = new Base();
Foo.constructor = Base();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way you call it, `this` in your Function.prototype.Inherits function would be the object created, not its constructor (Foo). You might want to remove the line `this.Inherits(Base);` and add this line after (and outside) the Foo declaration: `Foo.Inherits(Base);`

Comment: @Johan: His point was that doing things with the `this` is probably not what you want

Comment: Wouldnt it help to change `Function` to `Object` ?